# Selenium: How to verify whether an Element is Present

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: I have a scenario like after login to some page, a profile update button intermittently appears which i need to click on. Thing is like if that button will appear i have to click otherwise i have to leave that part and go ahead. I have written a logic to handle that scenario like below.

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By locatorKey) {
 try {
 getDriver().findElement(locatorKey);
 return true;
 } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
 return false;
 }
 }
```

If that element will appear it will return true otherwise it will return false.. The above code is working fine...but the problem is it is taking around one min to return either true or false..suppose i have used five places in my script so unnecessarily i the script is waiting for 5 mins...I have also tried the below code

```
getDriver().findElement(locator).isDisplayed();
```

But the same issue i am facing ...the code is working fine but it is also taking around 1 min to return the command...

Is there any efficient way to handle this kind of scenario without waiting one min to get the status?

Comment: Are you using implicit waits? In other words, do you have a line somewhere in your code that looks like `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60000)`? If so, that's why your wait takes so long to return.

Comment: That code shouldn't take a minute. In fact, it would likely execute immediately and then return false because the element hasn't appeared yet. Your problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: Implicit waiting sounds a viable culprit here

Answer (score 2):

Use method `findElements` instead, and check if the returned list is not empty:

```
return !getDriver().findElements(locatorKey).isEmpty();
```

Please note that a `try/catch` clause is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

barak manos has a perfectly viable answer to your question, but if you'd like to avoid the boolean inversion, here is an alternative:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By locatorKey){
    return (getDriver().findElements(locatorKey).size() > 0);
}
```

As with his solution, no try/catch is required for this as findElements() will simply return an empty list if the locator is not found or has gone stale.

Again, not to detract from barak manos here.  This is just another solution.

Comment: I originally used `size() > 0`. Then someone wrote I could use `isEmpty()`, so I figured it was "semantically" better. In both cases, the result is the same, in terms of both correctness and performance. Not that it matters much, but the `boolean` inversion actually takes place in **your solution**.

Comment: I have to disagree with you on the inversion point, given the context of the method (isElementPresent, implies true if present, false otherwise).  In order to return true when the element is found (and the list is not empty), one must invert the boolean using the ! operator.  .size() > 0 simply returns true if the list contains values, meaning one or more instances of the locator have been found.  It all comes down to preference, in this case.  If a particular approach works for you, is readable and manageable, then that's the best approach.  I had only meantto present an alternative.